# Diagram of Patent us6583327

Tags: us6583327

I haved seeked more diagrams of the continuous process of mononitrotoluene, but I haven't found them. Do you have a diagram for the patent us6583327?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use two sites for initial viewing of patents and applications. [Patents.google.com](https://patents.google.com) and [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/). This simple question was interesting in that it looks like this particular patent doesn't have any figures. I downloaded the PDF and in no place is the term "fig" or "figure" present. I also briefly read through the patent and couldn't find any references to figures or diagrams.  This may be the only patent I've seen without a figure. Here are links to the PDFs obtained from [patents.google.com](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/85256fbb14dd8c74aea4/US6583327.pdf) and [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/images/patent/US/6583327/B2/US_6583327_B2.pdf).

Comment: The cover page says that the patent has "No Drawings".  That's rare, but not impossible, as we see in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For the process patents it's not rare that there is no diagrams, figures, drawings, images nor illustrations. It's normal. It happens all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually many chemical and pharmaceutical patents don’t have figures since the structures are contained in/with the text.